# How do I use QuickCheck to test if a function terminates?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I would like to use QuickCheck to test a function to make sure it terminates (no infinite recursion, no exceptions thrown, etc.). This is what I do at the moment:

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int

prop_fTerminates :: Int -> Int -> Bool   -- say
prop_fTerminates x y = f x y `seq` True
```

Is there a better (more expressive and idiomatic) way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I probably wouldn't bother, I'd just test other properties of its output.

Any property that examines the output of `f x y` in any way is going to do *at least* as much termination checking as your `prop_fTerminates`, so why waste time doubling up on that check?

If for some reason "f x y terminates" is the only property you can test about `f`, then what you've got seems reasonable.

Comment: Yes, the problem is exactly that I cannot express any reasonable invariant about the output of `f`, which is actually the result of a Monte-Carlo calculation.

Answer (score 7):

This is the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). There is no algorithm capable of telling you whether a function terminates or not.

In particular, you *may* be able to get a positive result (i.e. if the function does terminate, this proposition will tell you) if you are willing to wait long enough. But just by waiting, you can never know the difference between *this function does not terminate* and *this function has not terminated yet*.

You can implement a check like *does this function terminate in time T* which may be appropriate for your needs.

---

**Edit** As written, your function does not do what you require. Consider

```
> let f = 1:f
> f `seq` True
True
```

The reason is that `seq` only evaluates to [weak head normal form](https://wiki.haskell.org/Weak_head_normal_form). Instead you could use `deepseq` which evaluates data structures deeply,

```
> import Control.DeepSeq (deepseq)
> f `deepseq` True
* never returns *
```

Comment: I don't want to _prove_ that the function terminates (that is the halting problem), I just want to make sure that I did not make any mistake in the implementation which would lead to infinite recursion. I would like to write my test in a way that clearly expresses my intention.

Comment: See my edit, which explains why `seq` is not appropriate here.

Comment: Well, `f` returns an `Int`, so WHNF and NF are the same, right? But in the general case you are definitely right.

Comment: You are correct that is undecidable in general, but there are ways to prove termination for many functions. Many theorem provers and software verification systems have to do this. For a functional language, a common idea is to define a well-defined order on the input term and then show via induction that the arguments of the recursive calls decrease in that order. It then follows that the function must terminate. Of course these systems do not work for every function, but it works often enough.

Comment: Yes, if you are only ever returning an `Int` then you don't need to worry about `seq` vs `deepseq`.